# What is the number of Gaussian chains of network per unit volume of rubber?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, polymers

In [this chapter](https://nspracticum.science.uu.nl/STF2018-2019/Practicum/ELAS/4020-Notes-7-text-book-rubber-elasticity.pdf), page 70, I encountered the term `Gaussian chains of network'. In equation 3.34 (page 73) of this chapter, the phrase 'n is the number of moles of Gaussian chains' occurs in the description of a formula which is also referred to in a laboratory guide document:

> An advanced three-dimensional molecular model of rubber elasticity (affine network model or freely jointed chain model, yields the equation of state
> $$f = n Ak_B(α − \frac{1}{α^2})T $$
> with n the number of polymer chains per unit volume, $A$ the cross-sectional area of the unstretched rubber band, and $α = L/L_0$ the ratio of the length to the unstretched length $L_0$.

Are there standard values on the internet for the number of Gaussian chains of network per unit volume of a rubber? Or maybe estimates or a rough indication? Can this value be expressed in other numbers which are easier to work with?

Comment: Note that "number of moles" is a layman synonymum for molar amount. We do not say "number of kilograms" either, but mass.

Comment: @BuckThorn I have intended my comment as the general note, not targetting anybody in particular. The document *repeatedly* writes **the number of moles of** near to the Eq. 3.34, but somewhere "of moles" is omitted.

Comment: @Poutnik Never mind. The document does use "moles of xxx". However since the OP is quoting verbatim a pass is allowed. Being stringent on the detail will not help much.

Comment: @BuckThorn I agree for number of moles vs molar amount. But "of moles" is kind of essential.

Comment: For readers, Gaussian chains are referred as "ideal gaussian chains (or freely-jointed chains)" in [Polymer Scattering Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_scattering) , leading to [Ideal Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_chain)